# Optimization involving expectation and positive part

Tags: probability, optimization, expectation, lagrange-multiplier, optimal-control

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem:

$$\max\limits_{x \in [0,\infty)} {\bf E} \left[ x \left( Z - a x \right)_+ - b \left( Z - ax \right)_+^2 \right],$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants, $(\cdot)_+$ denotes the positive part, 
${\bf E} [ \cdot ]$ is the expectation, and $Z$ is a random variable with a generic distribution function such that ${\bf E} [ Z^2 ] < \infty$ (if needed, we may assume higher-order moments of $Z$ exist).

Any idea to tackle this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for computational/numerical methodologies to perform the optimization?

Comment: I aim to find an analytical expression, if exists, of the maximizer of the problem, which I guess should be expressed in terms of $a$, $b$ and the distribution function of $Z$ (or moments of $Z$).

Comment: Why do you need a + sign on the square term?

Comment: That denotes the square of the positive part of Z - ax. When Z > ax, we  have (Z - ax)_+^2 = (Z - ax)^2. However, when Z < ax, the two expressions are different: the former is  (Z - ax)_+^2 = 0, the latter is (Z - ax)^2 > 0. I think the difficulty in this problem is caused by the signs of positive parts.